# PostMessage to DirectX9 -Game Character, Is it even possible?

Tags: visual-c++, directx, mouseevent, keyboard-events, postmessage

I have spent couple of days trying to force my way into pushing mouse clicks and keyboard impressions into a DirectX9 Game. So far, I have been able to use the login screen's user/password fields. Clicks and KB events are working.
Now when the game logs into the server, the flashy game intro comes up and then a seconds later, the actual play UI is visible. Text boxes, chat windows , etc are visible.
I am able to send the clicks into the chat window, press enter ,type ascii chars. etc. 
But I just cant seem to click on the actual "game character", or use the keyboard to control the character movements.

After lots and lots of searching, I am stuck at this point. Will DirectX honour my click/KB events? Is there a workaround for this? I know people will force me to hook our use SendInput() - My problem is that the game window is minimized so I cant use SendInput(), but I suspect that the arguments for PostMessage(gameWndHandle,WM_XXXXX,WPARAM,LPARAM) ,specifically WM_XXXXX are not "coerced" with those for DirectX, Which means my simple clicks are simply discarded.

For the sake of brevity. I am using the following

```
gameWndHandle = FindWindow("MyGame")
PostMessage(gameWndHandle,WM_KEYDOWN,(TCHAR)'a',NULL); // Works for chat box, not for a game character

PostMessage(gameWndHandle,MK_LBUTTON,NULL,MAKELPARAM(mouseX,mouseY)); // Works for chat box, not for a game character
```

I am sure someone must have cracked this. Is there an API for this? I mean any API mates? I hope someone can provide a link to a working sample. Seems like no one likes to share anymore :) Most probably a hook is the end solution I guess!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`SendInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

> The SendInput function inserts the events in the INPUT structures serially into the keyboard or mouse input stream.

Comment: That was what I was doing previously. I probably have took do it via hooks

Comment: Sorry, I saw PostMessage in code example and misread SendInput as SendMessage.

Comment: Have you seen [Sending Keystrokes to Games (DirectInput)](http://forum.sysinternals.com/sending-keystrokes-to-games-directinput_topic18025.html)?

Comment: Also, if you are sure that the PostMessage can help, try to log game's message processing with [API monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor).

Comment: I have checked all. The problem I have funneled down is to use DirectInput via hooking. Application with DirectInput poll the keyboard and mouse directly and skip normal messaging APIs.